# Trouble with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia with chrome on iPhone X

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, webcam, getusermedia

I am trying to give my browser access to my devices camera, so that I can feed the media stream into a video, but when I am testing on google chrome getUserMedia is not supported, but when I use safari I am having no issues.

Does google chrome not have any support for getUserMedia anymore?

I have already read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia), but have had no luck.

This is the implementation I am currently using:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    let constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: { facingMode: "user" }
    }

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia(constraints,
         function(stream) {
            var video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
              video.play();
            };
         },
         function(err) {
            alert("The following error occured: " + err.name);
         }
      );
   } else {
      console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

Having the same troubles on iOS 11.2x. My researches showed that FF and Chrome are supported on OS but NOT on iOS even they would be able to support media devices. You can test easy mediaDevice availability:

```
            if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
            alert ("Media device supported");
        }
        else {
            alert ("Media device not supported");
        }
```

You can check that here too: [HTML5Test](https://html5test.com)

FF and Chrome on iOS will show "Media device not supported" while Safari says its supported. The reason looks like Apple has still not given free the access to other browsers using mediaDevices.You can imagine some reasons why that is. ;/ So don't blame Chrome or Firefox this time.

Would be interesting to know if it now works in iOS 12.

Comment: september 2020, 
Chrome 84.0.4147.71 
OS: iOS
still doesn't work